# Defining step size of Emacs Macro Counter

Tags: emacs, macros, counter

I love the Emacs keyboard-macro functionality and I am using it a lot.

Sometimes, I don't want to just statically enter certain keyboard macros, but there should be a value there that will get changed in between. There is the feature of Emacs Macro counters ([Macro counters in Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macro-Counter.html)).

The problem is that this counter always just counts up by one. Is there a way to specify the stepping size (i.e. move forward by 4 in each step)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `kmacro-add-counter`, bound to <kbd>C-x C-k C-a</kbd>.
For example to add 3 to the counter, use <kbd>M-3 C-x C-k C-a</kbd>.

Small full example: `<f3> <f3> RET M-3 C-x C-k C-a <f4> <f4> <f4> <f4>` will produce:

```
0
4
8
12
```

### Alternative to `kmacro`

Sometimes, you can use [tiny](https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny) to do
what `kmacro` does in fewer keystrokes and with better undo context.

The above example can generated by entering:

```
m\n3*x4
```

and pressing the shortcut for `tiny-expand`. I bind it like this:

```cl
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'tiny-expand)
```

Here, `m\n3` basically means 4 repetitions (index starts from 0) joined by the newline character (`\n`). And `*x4` is a shorthand for Elisp `(* x 4)`.

Comment: Thanks! It is quite hacky and I was hoping that there would be an extra parameter there somewhere that I could set... But anyways... I guess that is the way I need to go :-)